# What is the operad for homotopy associative, homotopy commutative objects?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

There is an operad whose algebras are objects with a homotopy unital multiplication -- the $A_2$ operad.

There is an operad whose algebras are objects with a homotopy unital, homotopy associative objects -- the $A_3$ operad.

There is an operad $O$ whose algebras are homotopy associative, homotopy commutative objects. It may be constructed by generators and relations.

**Question 1:** Is there a more enlightening description of $O$? What are the connectivities / dimensionalities of its spaces, for instance?

**Question 2:** In particular, does $O$ coincide with the operad $A_2 \otimes A_2$, where $\otimes$ is the Boardman-Vogt tensor product?

Question 2 is suggested by the Eckmann-Hilton argument.

Comment: Intuitively, I would expect the $1$-skeleton of Kapranov's permutoassociahedron to be a model:  https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(93)90049-Y

Comment: It might not be the exact direction you are looking for, but [Hemmi-Kawamoto](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2004-356-10/S0002-9947-04-03647-5/) made use of the *permuto-associahedra* to define what they call $AC_n$-spaces. Their paper is very readable and the pair authored several similar papers.